# How to mock java.util.base64 methods using mockito

Tags: java, junit, mocking, base64, mockito

I have REST API  which returns json response 
i am writing test case for the REST api method using mockito

There is a xml response in the json so i am trying to encode the xml string in the json using Base64

My test case throws null pointer exception while executing the Base64.encode line in the REST api method

I cant use powermockito , its not used in the organisation 
how can i fix this issue using mockito itself

below is the line of code which throws error

```
Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString((message)).getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Here message is the xml string .

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you have to embed your XML in your JSON? Perhaps it would make for an easier API if you could transform your XML to JSON and not encode anything?

But, If you're sure you have to have XML nested in JSON, then you should pass `Base64.getEncoder()` result as your dependency in your class (Dependency Injection). Then mock it in your test, and pass the mock to your class.